# JavaScript crypto library can't encrypt and decrypt a string in a simple example program

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I am trying to learn JavaScript and am following a tutorial and I think I type everything in correctly but for some reason the string I encrypted using crypto-js library can't be unencrypted correctly.  I don't get an error but the unencrypted string is not correct.  I am using a macintosh and "crypto-js": "^3.1.5".

Here is my sample code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto-js');

var secretMessage = 'I hid the chips under the couch.';
var secretKey = '123abc';

var encryptedMessage = crypto.AES.encrypt(secretMessage, secretKey);
console.log('encryptedMessage: ' + encryptedMessage);

var bytes = crypto.AES.decrypt(encryptedMessage, secretKey);
var decryptedMessage = bytes.toString(crypto.enc.utf8);
console.log('decrpt2: ' + decryptedMessage);
```

Here are the results I get

```
   $ node example-encryption.js
    encryptedMessage: U2FsdGVkX180KTEpMiLEjZDSAkhNkmbBuRa9RXFwCgx6gA/PUFr+KOIv6Gr6TgIYrkfUu3F+OM/kRJ3sTTgsfg==
    decrpt2: 49206869642074686520636869707320756e6465722074686520636f7563682e
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Well, it's `crypto.enc.Utf8` and not `crypto.enc.utf8`. You're passing undefined which results in the default encoding, which is Hex.

Comment: I'm curious, why not use the built-in `crypto` module?

Comment: The one letter change made the difference. Thanks.

Comment: You can delete the question, because a typo question won't help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code, the main ones being that you need to supply a key of the right length and you also need to pass a cipherParams object to the decrypt() method rather than the ciphertext itself.

Here's some code that works and, for bonus points, is generally compatibable with the OpenSSL binaries and PHP libraries found on most systems:

```
var CryptoJS = require( 'crypto-js' );

var secretMessage = 'I hid the chips under the couch.';
var secretKey = 'b52b4f45b6e9337b57869d7cb718c693';

var encryptedMessage = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(secretMessage, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(secretKey),
                       { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding });

console.log('encryptedMessage: ' + encryptedMessage.ciphertext);

cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create(
               {ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedMessage.ciphertext.toString())});

var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams,CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(secretKey),
            { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding });

console.log( 'Decrypted:' + bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

There is no Initiatlization Vector because we're using ECB rather than CBC. If you want something secure, use CBC with a random IV for every message.